# iOS 6 NavigationController not loading

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app that I migrated over from iOS 5 to iOS 6 and am having trouble with the UINavigationController not displaying correctly.

In my app, the user must login and they are presented that login screen in a modal view after pressing a button.

```
WelcomeViewController.m
- (IBAction)signInButtonSelected:(id)sender
{
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
}
```

The view loads correctly and has lets the user enter their login credentials. However, when they press the login button, the next view is presented and it SHOULD have a UINavigationBar at the top, except it doesn't. If I quit the app and restart it, the UINavigationBar shows up in that view properly. I have not a clue as to why going from the login view to the logged in screen hides the navigation controller.

Here is the code that is executed when the login button is pressed that loads the next view:

```
LoginViewController.m
WallViewController *wallViewController = [[WallViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
         [(UINavigationController *)self.presentingViewController pushViewController:wallViewController animated:YES];
         [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

If anyone can shed some light on to why this is happening that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any warnings in the console? The problem might be 2 transitions happening at the same time. Try passing NO as the animated parameter to pushViewController:animated:.

Comment: why not you use pushViewController and PopViewController with NavigationController?

Comment: When using pushViewController with animated set to NO, there are no errors in the console and the view is dismissed and the specified view is loaded, but with no navigation bar. When using popToViewController i get an error that the viewController does not exists.

Comment: I copied your code, and couldn't reproduce your results. It worked fine for me. Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: Interesting...I am using XIB files for now, but may switch to storyboards if they handle it better.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter whether you use xibs or storyboards (as long as nothing is set up wrongly in the storyboard). Is this extensive code? Are you sure there's no navigationBarHidden = YES somewhere?

Comment: I have checked everywhere in every file that gets loaded for the navBar to be hidden, but can not find anywhere that it is. It's very strange that it will not load the NavBar when switching from another view but will if you quit the app in the multitasking menu then relaunch it

Comment: When you relaunch it, does it go through a different sequence? Do you still get the login screen? You can do a project wide search using the  search navigator on the left side of the Xcode window, just to be sure.

Comment: Upon launch of the app, it check's if the user is logged in and if it does see they already are, it goes to the WallViewController. The app delegate does the user checking and loading of the wall view controller if it does find a user.

Comment: Well, I'm stumped. I can't think of any other reasons why you would get this behavior.

Comment: @BrianR you said you using xib files and why is your initWithNibName nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. In my App Delegate, I had placed:

```
navController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

And it would hide the navigation bar after a user would login. Not exactly sure why this in the app delegate would affect a view later on down the line. But once it was removed, it works perfectly!

Thanks for the help!